# Ubuntu 16.04 server no network

Tags: networking

this is my first time setting up a server. I have a [Huawei RH1288 V3](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/intelligent-servers/rh1288-v3-pid-9901873) set and ready. Upon connecting the lan cable from my router to the server, I realise that there were no green lights coming from both ends. I plugged it into my laptop and I had ethernet connection.

The first thing I tried was to command sudo apt-get update and received an error. It was a long error1 error 2 error3  saying failure to retrieve and failed to fetch from some domain. I have tried looking at some of the post here to no avail.

In the iBMC WebUI of this server, it displays the NIC with two ports and MAC addresses each but the link status is disconnected even when it is connected.

Is there something wrong with my network card or is there some network configuration that has to be done for this server to be up and running?

I will add photos tomorrow.

Comment: You may have to edit /etc/netplan/*.yaml for your configuration. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: No telltale LEDs by the LAN Ports? Those are supposed to be always-on. Confirm that by booting from a LiveUSB of Ubuntu 18.04.